# Nexus 5 Google Maps API 3 Geo-location bug?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, nexus-5

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I am trying to build a site and I need to detect a users location and I have come across what I think is a bug with the Nexus 5.

Just wondering if someone could validate it is in fact an issue or point me in the direction of a solution (searched but can't find anything).

When I go to

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

on my computer and grant permission to detect my location, it comes up fine.

When I go to the same link on my phone and grant permission to detect my location, the map doesn't load.

I initially thought it was something I was doing, but when I went to the W3Schools example:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

And click the "Try It" button, on my computer, it returns a result, but again, when click the link on my phone, I am not getting any response.

A mate tried both links on his iphone, they worked.

Anyone with a Nexus 5 can help or if it is a known bug?

Cheers.